# Type "codechefRoot" does not conform to protocol Decodable

Tags: swift, structure

Why is it the error occurring only for "codechefRoot" while other struct objects work just fine?

I mean codechefRoot is as same as other struct objects, why the error occurring only at it.

```swift
import Foundation

struct codeforcesRoot: Decodable {
    var status: String
    var result: [codeforcesData]
}

struct codeforcesData: Decodable {
    var handle: String
    var rank: String
    var rating: Int
}

struct interviewbitRoot: Decodable {
    var rank: String
    var score: String
    var streak: String
}

struct codechefRoot: Decodable {
    var rank: String
    var global_rank: String
    var country_rank: String
    var contest: [contestsData]
}

struct contestsData {
    var name: String
    var rating: String
    var global_rank: String
    var country_rank: String
}
```

Comment: Usually you want to copy and paste code, because links get deleted or changed and pasting it here is more readable

Comment: sorry I didn't get you. You want me to paste the code ?

Comment: You posted the link of the image of your code, but in SO, it's more readable to post the actual code. Nvm though I typed it out

Comment: Oh yeah, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because your `contestsData` type does not conform to `Decodable`.

By changing `struct contestsData {..}`
to `struct contestsData: Decodable {..}` should fix it